# How to overlap a div to an another div without changing their positions - Css

Tags: html, css, css-position, overlap

I have two divs on the top of the webpage. I just want to overlap the shadow of the top div to the following one. Absolute and relative positioning completely changed the positions/places of divs by either expanding or fixing position. Is there a line of code that just achieves to decide which div will be overlapped and which div won't be without changing their positions? If there is not, how I can do this with posititioning?
My top div:

```
div#divSlogan{
    background-color: #FFBD01;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: -1.15%;
    padding: 0.1%;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px #888888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px #888888;
    box-shadow:  0px 0px 10px 2px #888888;
}
```

The following div:

```
div#menu{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 120%;
    background-color: #FFA700;
    padding: 0.1%;
    height: 20%;
    width: 49%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

My webpage:

[image]

All in all, I want to put the shadow of the top div (which is written Listen. Enjoy..) to the following below div (which is menu). How can I do this?

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle with your code?

Comment: what you need is z-index for the second one. give it a lower z-index than the first. and both have to be positioned at least relative.

Comment: @Stefan no, I didn't use it so far. I am also using apache wicket which allows me to use wicket:panel. I dont think this site work with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use absolute positioning for this .I'm not sure why relative positioning didn't work for you . To use z-index you need to use absolute , relative or static position .
Here is the working code , replace the div#menu by this in your css file  .

```
div#menu{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 120%;
    background-color: #FFA700;
    padding: 0.1%;
    height: 20%;
    width: 49%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position:relative;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Edit 1:
You have to use position relative here because z-index won't work otherwise .

Here is a JSFiddle of this working: http://jsfiddle.net/pezrwv0z/3/

Edit 2 : 
Other things that can be improved in the code .
Instead of margin-left:auto ; margin-right:auto; use

```
margin:0 auto ;
```

To center the div .

```
height:20%;
```

You can't give height a value in % , use pixels (px) instead . eg: height:50px;

Edit 3 : 
It seems that links don't work in a container with negative z-index . 
Here is the updated fiddle . http://jsfiddle.net/pezrwv0z/3/

Comment: Nevermind I see your post above you said it correctly.  But just seeing the Edit at the bottom I thought you meant just relative.  You are correct :)

Comment: Happy to help :) , why the hell are people downvoting this answer :P

Comment: I just realize it crashes my menu. The links are gone and are not clicked.

Comment: Normally I don't ask this but can you post a live link so I can see what you are talking about or is this local?

Comment: Unfortunately it is local

Comment: Can you post the HTML code you are using for the div#menu and div#divSlogan please.  I will try to figure it out.

Comment: I can post it but this divs are created using apache wicket panel property, so just you will see placeholders instead of links. Still post it?

Comment: @SiddharthSharma thank you for edit 3 but still I have same problem, The links are gone and not clickable anymore. How can I solve it?

Comment: Anything can be wrong including the container where you have placed the menu div and other div . If you create a fiddle on jsfiddle.net , I'll be able to look over that .

Comment: @SiddharthSharma Please tell me if you cannot find a solution and then I post a new question about this.

Comment: It seems that links don't work in a container with negative z-index ,I have made the edit to the original fiddle . Here is the link , http://jsfiddle.net/pezrwv0z/3/ .

Answer (score 0):

Try changing div#menu to - should do the trick:

```
div#menu {
text-align: center;
font-size: 120%;
background-color: #FFA700;
padding: 0.1%;
height: 20%;
width: 49%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
/* add these */
margin-top: -10px;
/* z-index: 3; - this was the wrong way around, ignore this line :) */
z-index: -1;
}
```

Edit: not too sure on the margin-top - might be more appropriate to change margin-bottom on the slogan div - again, a negative value of your choosing.

Comment: This is going to pull the menu up.  It is already above the slogan, OP wants it the opposite.

Comment: Yup, you're right. My bad. I've corrected the suggested answer (leaving in my mistake, so your comment isn't made redundant).

Comment: Both your soluions didn't work. In your edit, You mean to change margin-bottom on the slogan div with a negative value and z-index: 3; still remains in the menu div, don't you?